# /dev/sda not appearing after secure erase

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, devices, io, ssd

I decided to wipe my SSD with a secure erase before installing Arch Linux, since the Arch wiki said that it would improve performance. I followed [the instructions listed on the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSD_Memory_Cell_Clearing), but now when I attempt to install Arch, `/dev/sda` does not show up and errors about I/O are given.

When I run `fdisk -l`, the following error log appears:

```
end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
Buffer I/O error on device sda, logical block 0
sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
sd 0:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Input/output error
```

A few other errors also appear at boot, saying:

```
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.00L status { DRDY }
```

The SSD appears in the BIOS, and it also appears in the hardware detection tool on the Arch LiveCD. I tried booting with GParted, Ubuntu, and Gentoo, but none of the other OSes would create `/dev/sda` either.

`/dev/sda` does not appear in `fdisk`, `testdisk`, or any other tools.

I've spent hours trying to make progress on this issue. Does anyone know of a solution?

Here's the complete log of dmesg: http://sprunge.us/RCgY

Comment: Well, after all it's called secure erase... Seriously, you read the warning on the wiki, didn't you: "Do not proceed with this if your drive isn't connected directly to a SATA interface. Issuing the Secure Erase command on a drive connected via USB or a SAS/RAID card could potentially brick the drive!"

Comment: Unfortunately, I was under the impression that since it was a single SSD it would be connected via SATA. After researching the error more, I realize now that SSDs actually use RAID. Is there a possible solution besides RMAing it?

Comment: Ow... sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: Can you download a tool from the manufacturer's website to repartition the drive? Unfortunately the manufacturers only seem to provide them for Windows, so if you don't have access to a Windows box, then this won't help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into that. I'm also downloading a trial of Windows 8.1 to see if I can partition the drive using Windows and then install Arch or Gentoo after that.